# TSQL - Returning single value on if any row exists?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

So I have a view that I want to return one row for each user, with some fields brought in (joined) from other tables. Everything works, except the last part.

One of the tables has multiple rows associated with the user, and I want one of the values in the row the view returns to be 0/1 if ANY of the lookup rows have a value. The view:

```
CREATE VIEW [VW_USER_LIST]
AS
    SELECT  USR.*, 
        UPL.FIRST_NAME, 
        UPL.LAST_NAME, 
        UPL.MIDDLE_INITIAL, 
        UPL.LDAP_DN, 
        UPL.RSS_TOKEN, 
        UPL.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
        UPL.TIMEZONE, 
        UPL.CULTURE,
        (RTRIM(UPL.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + ISNULL(UPL.MIDDLE_INITIAL,'')) + ' ' + UPL.LAST_NAME) AS FULL_NAME,
        UPOM.ORGANIZATION_ID AS ORGANIZATION_ID,
        UPO.NAME AS ORGANIZATION_NAME,
        UPOM.ORGANIZATION_ROLE_ID AS ORGANIZATION_ROLE_ID,
        CASE WHEN ROL.ROLE_ID IS NULL THEN CONVERT(bit,0) ELSE CONVERT(bit,1) END AS ISINTERNAL
    FROM [USER] AS USR 
        INNER JOIN [USER_PROFILE] AS UPL ON USR.USER_ID = UPL.USER_ID
        LEFT JOIN [USER_ORGANIZATION_MEMBERSHIP] AS UPOM ON USR.USER_ID = UPOM.USER_ID
        LEFT JOIN [ORGANIZATION] AS UPO ON UPOM.ORGANIZATION_ID = UPO.ORGANIZATION_ID
        LEFT JOIN [USER_ROLE] AS URL ON USR.USER_ID = URL.USER_ID
        LEFT JOIN [ROLE] AS ROL ON URL.ROLE_ID = ROL.ROLE_ID AND ROL.IS_INTERNAL=1
```

The check that I am the closest to use is the last one there before the 'FROM', the 'CASE'. Returns a `BIT` value of 0 or 1. It's matching JOIN is the last JOIN in the list.

However, if a user has two entries in the `USER_ROLE` that are marked `IS_INTERNAL=1` in the table, then the view is returning two entries for that user.

And I understand why.

However, apparently what I NEED is to use the `EXISTS`, `DISTINCT`, `ANY`, or another singular check on that join - but can't find a good example of how to pull that off - **if it's even possible**.

And to clarify, the `USER_ROLE` table may have multiple entries for the `USER_ID`, cross-referenced to the `ROLE` table. So if the user has ANY entry in the `USER_ROLE` table that has a matching `ROLE_ID` with an entry in the `ROLE` table with `IS_INTERNAL = 1`. Yeah, there's a lot of steps there!

Comment: When you looked at the EXISTS() function in MSDN and tried to follow the examples there, what did you try and what error did you get?

Comment: You should not use USR.* when creating a view. It will give you problem in the future if the [USER] table has any change in its columns.

Comment: @DVT  Yeah, I know. The actual view doesn't - I just did that to trim down the lines. :) Didn't wanna spam the question with 50+ columns. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
CREATE VIEW [VW_USER_LIST]
AS
    SELECT  USR.*, 
        UPL.FIRST_NAME, 
        UPL.LAST_NAME, 
        UPL.MIDDLE_INITIAL, 
        UPL.LDAP_DN, 
        UPL.RSS_TOKEN, 
        UPL.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
        UPL.TIMEZONE, 
        UPL.CULTURE,
        (RTRIM(UPL.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + ISNULL(UPL.MIDDLE_INITIAL,'')) + ' ' + UPL.LAST_NAME) AS FULL_NAME,
        UPOM.ORGANIZATION_ID AS ORGANIZATION_ID,
        UPO.NAME AS ORGANIZATION_NAME,
        UPOM.ORGANIZATION_ROLE_ID AS ORGANIZATION_ROLE_ID,
        ISINTERNAL = cast(case when exists (select 1
                                            from [role] rol
                                            where url.role_id = rol.rol_id
                                                and rol.is_internal = 1) then 1 
                               else 0 
                          end as bit)
    FROM [USER] AS USR 
        INNER JOIN [USER_PROFILE] AS UPL ON USR.USER_ID = UPL.USER_ID
        LEFT JOIN [USER_ORGANIZATION_MEMBERSHIP] AS UPOM ON USR.USER_ID = UPOM.USER_ID
        LEFT JOIN [ORGANIZATION] AS UPO ON UPOM.ORGANIZATION_ID = UPO.ORGANIZATION_ID
        LEFT JOIN [USER_ROLE] AS URL ON USR.USER_ID = URL.USER_ID
```

Comment: Unfortunately, gives the same result. Not your fault, though - I forgot to mention the link. Main question will be updated with the missing info.